# UIScrollView does not fill whole screen

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, scrollview

[image]

I have a UIScrollView which is set up with AutoLayout.  I have a constraint on the "Save" button from the bottom of the button to the bottom of the scrollview, set to 0.  The scrollview also has a bottom constraint of zero to the superview.  Meaning, that the Save button SHOULD be 0 pixels away from the bottom, and even says so on the attributes inspector (see screenshot).  How come, when I run the project, or even view from the storyboard, that this button is NOT at the bottom of the screen?  Why is the save button refusing to align on the bottom of the scrollview and thus the bottom of the screen?

Comment: have you any constraint exception with this contraints?

Comment: are you setting the constraint in the any:any size class?

Comment: No i am not setting it in the any:any size class.  And I dont believe I have any constraint exceptions

Answer (score 1):

According to this article: https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/ , the best way to deal with scrollview is to make sure only one view (we will call this contentView) is within the scrollview.  Place all the subviews within contentView, and the trick is to use equal height and width from the scrollview to that contentView.  I was able to solve my issue that way.